# Why isn't there a "save as" option in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In Jupyter notebook, after I click File->New Notebook, the file is stored to the root home directory of my anaconda installation. Why isn't there a "save as" option to allow save the new notebook to a directory which I created myself? I have to move the file in my terminal. I am just curious about. Is that possible? That seems a common use case.

Answer (score 0):

The notebook you are creating with the "new" button, saves it under the directory you are currently under when pressing that button.

There is also the "save as" option in both jupyter and jupyterlab, as soon as it is already created.

In jupyter:
[image: jupyter save as]

In Jupyterlab:
[image: jupyterlab save as]